# How to create multi page form?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to make a form with two pages for a models class Student. I am currently trying to pass the data from first page into a controller which will pass the student as a model to my second page view which will then pass to the controller to save to my database but only the data from the second page is being saved to DB.

Page 1

```
@model Student
<body>
    <div class="container1">
        <form asp-action="Page2" method="post" role="form">
            <div class=" form-group row">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Page 2

```
@model Student
    <body>
        <div class="container1">
            <form asp-action="Submit" method="post" role="form">
                <div class=" form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="LastName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Page2(Reports report)
        {

            return View(report);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Submit(Reports report)
        {
            _reportRepository.CreateReport(report);
            return View(report);
        }
```

Comment: As far as I understand you missed`_reportRepository.CreateReport(report);` in `Page2` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a form field for FirstName to the view for Page2, either a hidden field or (assuming you don't want it modified) a read-only input.

```
<input asp-for="FirstName" type="hidden" />
```

or

```
<input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" readonly />
```

Only values that have some sort of [successful control](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) are included in any form submission. This is true for any plain old HTML form, which is (once your view is generated) really what you're dealing with.

If you're coming from a WebForms background, there is no ViewState in any version of the MVC Framework (Full framework or .NET Core), so it's up to you as the developer to persist those values across requests.

Comment: Thank you! that is what I was looking for.